# Why don't I get my reputation back when I answer the question myself?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I posted [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26601/new-computer-hangs-on-shutdown-reboot-how-to-troubleshoot/27976#27976) to my own question on which I had set a bounty. I lost the rep immediately when I set the bounty = OK, that's expected. I didn't get the bounty back when I added the best answer and accepted that = not OK, I had expected the bounty, based on how Superuser.com works.... so why didn't I get my bounty back?

(Please note that I'm not whining, I just want to understand the reason.)

Answer (score 3):

It has always worked the way you describe, see and compare

https://superuser.com/faq#bounty

https://askubuntu.com/faq#bounty

Comment: Okay. But why didn't I get the bounty back when I awarded it to myself? Is it to avoid cheating?

Comment: @tobengb If you think about it makes sense, otherwise people would be awarding bounties to themselves to get the extra exposure and it wouldn't cost them anything.

Comment: @Jorge, yes that does make sense!