# Can I award bounty to my own answer?

Tags: support, bounty

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is a user not allowed to give the bounty to himself?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1358/is-a-user-not-allowed-to-give-the-bounty-to-himself)

I had answered a question and got many upvotes for it. However, the asker accepted another answer as the correct one. I started a bounty on that question saying that one of the answers were exemplary (my own) and it was worth an additional bounty. However, I do not see a button that allows me to award my bounty for my own answer.

Now if the bounty expires, the FAQ says that the bounty award's half will be given to the most upvoted answer. So will I get half of the bounty that I offered?

The question is [What downloaders are available for downloading large (over 1 GB) files part by part?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129854/what-downloaders-are-available-for-downloading-large-over-1-gb-files)

Comment: This question I think is a variation of this one: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1066/why-dont-i-get-my-reputation-back-when-i-answer-the-question-myself?rq=1 or possibly this one: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1358/is-a-user-not-allowed-to-give-the-bounty-of-his-question-to-himself?rq=1

Comment: Unfortunately, to prevent abuse, you can't award bounty to your own answer. And either way, the bounty would be given to the answer most upvoted and was created after the bounty was started.

Comment: So basically that means I'm going to lose that rep huh? I guess there should be a better way to bring more attention to a good answer.